# Exposed Filters in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

I am not able to get exposed filters to work in Drupal 8.  Here is a screenshot to help me while I explain some of the issues
 [image]

I want to filter by the title of a content type.  This title was renamed to "Name" as you can see me trying to put it in the value for the operator to compare.  This value seems to be the default since when I try this, "Name" is in the field and not grabbing any nodes.  Without anything inside the Value box, nothing is coming up for my queries when testing this filter.

So how do exposed filters work in Drupal 8?   Nothing I have tried has gotten any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposed filters do work in 8.0.2, although there are limits of to how well you can format or alter them.

But you want to do should work fine.  Looking at your uploaded image, though, suggests you don't quite have it configured right for what you want to do.  I'd recommend that you leave "Value" blank, and choose "Contains" as the operator. Under "Advanced", check "Use AJAX". Once you "Apply" to the display, you'll see a preview at the bottom of the view edit window.  If you start typing the name (i.e., title) of one of your nodes, you'll see that the list of nodes at the bottom of the window indeed updates as you type.